# How to create a before insert trigger based on previously inserted values in the table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table which contains two columns
1.Clanid
2.Active

My problem is that i dont want any value in Clanid column to be inserted in this table if this value is already in Clanid column and Active for that value is 1.

For example 
  Clanid  Active
  1              1
  2               1
  3               0

Now it should not be possible to insert a record with Clanid=1 and Active=1 but i can insert Clanid=3 and Active=1 as this record is not there.

Comment: Define a `unique key( clanid, active )`

Comment: But with active=0, there can be multiple records with same clanid.

Comment: Yes, With this *combo key*, you can have `'3,0'`, `'3,1'`, `'3,x'` etc. and will not be repeating the same combination.

Comment: Is it possible with combo key to have '3,0' multiple times but '3,1' only once

Comment: For such odd occurrences, handle in your application level.

Comment: But this can be handeled at database level also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
delimiter //
create trigger unique_clanid
before insert on mytable
for each row
begin
  if new.active and exists (
    select * from mytable
    where clanid = new.clanid
    and active) then
    signal sqlstate '02000' set MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate ClanID';
  end if;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle in your app level, but you want to handle in DB lavel, you can write trigger check it
you can check count record ( where Clanid = @param and Active =1) 
if count > 1 : rollback

I am not available mysql to test , i just can describe my solution as following ( i;m not sure the syntax correct, it is too long time i don't write trigger in mysql)

`CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE newClanId integer;
    DECLARE counts integer;
     Set @newClanId = NEW.Clanid;
     Set @count := (SELECT count (*) FROM table_name
          WHERE Clanid = @newClanId and Active =1)
     IF @count > 1 THEN ROLLBACK;
  END;`

Comment: i am new to triggers, but can you please elaborate your answer, i know it will take time but this will help me alot.I am trying to create a constraint using this trigger. Thanks.

Comment: @user3454311 you can see more at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html Hope useful for you